# Как написать анализатор строки для калькулятора?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, калькулятор

Как разработать анализатор? Есть строка, которая вводится, интерпретируеться программой, которая выполняет нужные действия, заданные пользователем в строке. Реализовать простые арифметические операции (/ * - +). Например, при вводе строки "2 плюс 5" или "2 + 5", результатом программы должно быть "7".

Comment: А в чем проблема? Спарсить число, потом операцию, потом еще одно число и вернуть результат.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ прочитав все ответы, не пришел к пониманию как реализовать мою задачу.

Comment: Ну тут уж извиняйте, от нас тогда вы что хотите? Чтоб мы те ответы вам еще раз написали? Извините, это, во-первых, по правилам SO плохо (ибо дубликат), а во-вторых, бессмысленно, ибо вы так или иначе не поймете, не подумав и не попробовав самостоятельно. Так что советую еще раз прочитать и самостоятельно попробовать.